# A way to copy with scp several sub-directories

Tags: bash, copy-paste, glob

I have thousands of directories with 3 or 5 sub-directories each, like this:

```
/directory1/sub1
/directory1/sub2
/directory1/sub3
/directory2/sub1
/directory2/sub2
/directory2/sub3
...
```

I want to copy all sub-directories sub2 to another location on the network using the command scp but I don't want to go one by one obviously. How is the best way to do this with a bash script or a terminal command?

The directories can have very different names because the names were created using md5 hashing but the sub-directories I want to copy all have the same name.

Comment: `scp -r directory*/sub2 host:/path/to/remote/directory`?

Comment: All the different sub2 directories to one destination?

Comment: This Question is also better suited for superuser

Comment: @0x5453 that worked! thanks

Comment: `rsync -rav directory*/* user@example.com:/destionation/path` benefits of using `rsync` is that it's designed for this sort of thing, it compresses before transferring so it makes it a lot faster than `scp`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For every directory in the current folder (except for the hidden ones starting with ".") create them with ssh

```
remote_dir="~/user/folder/"
remote_ip="..."
for dir in $(find . -type d ! -wholename './.*'); do
    echo Creating: $remote_dir${dir#'./'} #removes ./ from directory name
    ssh "user@$remote_ip" "mkdir -p $remote_dir${dir#'./'}"
done
```

then send all files recursively:

```
scp -r * "user@$remote_ip:$remote_dir"
```